# How to get Firebase users by Google Play Store account used to download the app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm developing an Android app where the owner of the app (Google Play Store account) can sign in using Google sign-in and Email/Password options offered by Firebase Authentication.

Let's first consider the following scenario:

1. User downloads the app with Google Play Store account having email: user123@gmail.com
2. User signs into the app using Google sign-in option with email: user123@gmail.com (same as Play Store account)
3. User signs into the app using Google sign-in option with email: user456@gmail.com
4. User signs into the app using Email/Password option with email: testuser@yahoo.com

Now there are three `FirebaseUser`s created via steps 2 to 4 above.

Does Firebase offer a way to find out which Google Play Store account all these three users have been created with (in the above case this would be user123@gmail.com)? I need some sort of grouping option in order to show a list of users which have been created through the app.

I've been able to implement the authentication code properly and have been able to retrieve data of one user successfully but don't know how to show all users created by a single physical user of the app.

Any help would be a greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase docs go through the process step by step as seen in the link. Is there a particular part that is not working or that you have a question about. Essentially when the user first does a login with Google, that create the token, and then subsequently if they login with another method they link the two accounts and then in Firebase's auth they are one user with multiple sign-in methods.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking?authuser=0

Comment: Didn't get it. In step 2 and 3 in my question, the user signed in with two different Google accounts. Are these allowed to be linked with each other? Secondly, in step 4, the user signed in using Email/Password method, now which Google account (step 2 or 3) it would be linked to?